# Transfer Function of Electrical System

Tags: circuit-analysis, transfer-function, kirchhoffs-laws

I am trying to find the transfer function \$\frac{V_{out}(s)}{V_{in}(s)}\$ of an electrical system that operates according to the diagram below.

[image: Circuit schematic with a L in series with R1 in series with, C1 and R2 in parallel]

\$V_{in}\$ is switched between 0 and 13 Volts (i.e \$V_{in}(t) = 13u(t)\$)

It also assumes that initially the Capacitor and Inductor are de-energised initially.

I am assuming that the first step is to apply a KVL analysis to the circuit. I have attempted but can't seem to get anything correct. Was hoping someone could help me clarify this problem and the steps taken.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI, EE.SE uses `\$` instead of just `$` for inline math.

Comment: Do you know how to find the impedance of an inductor or capacitor in the s-domain?

Answer (score 3):

> \$V_{in}\$ is switched between 0 and 13 Volts (i.e \$V_{in}(t) = 13u(t)\$)

You don't need to know this to find the transfer function.

After you know the transfer function, you can multiply it by the Laplace-domain equivalent of the input voltage to get the output voltage.

> I am assuming that the first step is to apply a KVL anaylsis to the circuit.

That would work but it can also be done just using parallel and series combinations, along with the voltage divider formula, to get the transfer function. First step is to find the Laplace-domain representations for each circuit element.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the transfer function and plotting Bode plots.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Using KCL, the current in \$L1\$ and \$R1\$ is the sum of the currents in \$C1\$ and \$R2\$.

$$\frac{Vin-Vout}{L1 s + R1}=\frac{Vout}{\frac{1}{C1 s}}+\frac{Vout}{R2}$$

We can solve this equation for \$Vout\$ and get the expression for \$\frac{Vout}{Vin}\$.

```
Vout/Vin /. Solve[(Vin - Vout )/(R1 + s L1) == Vout/(1/(s C1 )) + Vout/R2, Vout][[1]]
```

> $$\frac{R2}{R1 + R2 + L1 s + C1 R1 R2 s + C1 L1 R2 s^2}$$

We can then substitute the numerical values

```
%/. {R1 -> 50 10^-3, L1 -> 50 10^-3, C1 -> 100 10^-6, R2 -> 1} // N
```

> $$\frac{1}{1.05 + 0.050005 s + 5* 10^{-6} s^2}$$

And get the response to the step input

```
OutputResponse[TransferFunctionModel[%, s], 13, t] // Simplify
```

> $$\left\{12.381\, +0.0261597 e^{-9979.96 t}-5.29395*10^{-18} e^{-9958.92 t}-12.4071 e^{-21.0422 t}\right\}$$

```
Plot[%, {t, 0, 0.3}]
```

> [image]